# What would be the best way to build an online business directory that uses structured data (JSON-LD)?

Tags: json, wordpress, web-services, user-interface, web-frameworks

Please bear with me...

I have list of businesses that I would like to feature on a website.  The businesses are all collated in a .csv file.  Is there any way to quickly import these businesses into a content-management-system so that their business information is displayed in an online directory, a boilerplate landing-page for each business is generated, and key business information is encoded in structured data (schema.org) both on the directory listing and the landing-page?

Is there a framework I could use to do this quickly.  I would like to publish this site using Wordpress but I'm not sure if it would be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

hmm... have you tried searching for a plugin?

Here is one to get you started:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Comment: I need to get my point up so I could up-vote you.  Thank you!